# NullPointerException in Hash Map

Tags: java, hashmap

In our Prod environment today we saw following NPE :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
    at java.util.HashMap$TreeNode.putTreeVal(HashMap.java:1970) 
    at java.util.HashMap.putVal(HashMap.java:637) 
    at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:611)
```

We have used null as a key in our Map but as per docs it is allowed in java.

I am trying to understand if there is any way that put method will produce NPE or not as we have to give proper Root Cause for the same.

If some one has any Idea about it like put method can throw NPE please share.

Comment: can you show us your code please?

Comment: This looks like a race condition. Are you accessing the map from multiple threads?

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve] to reproduce this case ? It would be nice to see how you generate that runtime-exception.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using java 8 then you will get NPE for null as a key.

See the bug at https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8046085

Comment: @AxelH the bug only happens when the map switches to tree mode due to a high number of collisions, and the fix version is 9. So it has been fixed, but in Java 9, not in Java 8. Also, you seem to think that OpenJDK is some kind of exotic implementation of Java. It's not. It's the standard JDK that basically everybody uses, on which Oracle folks work.

Comment: It's already fixed in Java8, check the "backports" of the fix: java8u26, that's 2014. The current version is 1.8.0_131-b11. So it can happen if you haven't updated the JRE since then (something not unusual in production environments)